# Getting an image to imagelist1 when listview1 item is selected

Tags: vb.net

Error: The path is not of a legal form. (Message box shows empty path/message).

```
If (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
        Dim selection As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
        PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(selection.Text)
End If
```

Comment: The selection text would ideally be the file name of the image.

Comment: @farook: So the [Text of your ListView-Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text.aspx) is an empty string instead of the path to the image, does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
If (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
    try
        Dim selection As string = ListView1.FocusedItem.text
        PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(selection)
    catch ex as Exception
        msgbox (ex.message.tostring)
    enD Try
End If
```

Comment: The path is not of a legal form!

Comment: It does not solve my problem. Basically what I want is for the imagelist1 to display a selected image from listview1.

Comment: Tim, let's change my code to a code you may recommend. I've tried the code from your link. It displays check boxes in the listview1.

Comment: Let's disregard this question. How can I delete (current image) in imagelist1? Add images too does not work. The image adds to the listview1 but is not permanently added to imagelist1.